# How to pack jobs in bash and make output directory tree nested in parent?

Tags: bash, sed

After running this script I am getting job_1 directory inside job_0, job_2 directory inside job_1 etc I would like to have job_1,job_2,...job_63 directories inside just one directory job_0. What I need to change in my script in order for that to happen?

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzLUD.png)

```
#!/bin/bash 
njobs=64
nprocs_per_job=32
let total_procs=($njobs * $nprocs_per_job)
sed 's/^.*width.*$/\#PBS -l mppwidth='$total_procs'/' qscript_test > tmp
mv tmp qscript
for (( i = 0; i < $njobs ; i++  ))
do
mkdir job_$i
cd job_$i
echo "cd job_$i" >> qscript
echo "aprun -n $nprocs_per_job python hello.py &" >> qscript
echo "cd .." >> qscript
done
echo "wait" >> qscript
qsub qscript
```

Comment: Please post the code itself, not a picture of it.

Answer (score 0):

take some iterations of your loop as an example:

when `i = 0`

```
mkdir job_0; cd job_0
```

so now the working directory is `job_0`.

when `i = 1`

```
mkdir job_1; cd job_1
```

so now your dir structure is `job0/job1` and your working directory is `job1`. `mkdir job_2` will only create `job_0/job_1/job_2` so this loop only nests directories.

you should first create `job_0`, `cd` into it and then proceed with the loop, adding to it that it should return to the previous directory in every iteration:

```
mkdir job_0
cd job_0  # change CWD to job_0
for (( i = 1; i < $njobs ; i++  )); do
    mkdir job_$i
    cd job_$i  # change CWD to job_n
    aprun -n $nprocs_per_job python hello.py >> qscript &  # execute command in background and append the stdout to qscript file
    cd ..  # change CWD to job_0
done
cd ..  # change CWD to the starting point
```

i'm limiting myself to change as little of your code as possible, however there are cleaner ways to do this, don't forget to check: [`pushd/popd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands)
and/or [subshells](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)

Comment: it makes the file structure I want but hello.py doesn't run.

Comment: for example in /job_0/job_1 in qscript I have: cd job_1
aprun -n 32 python /lustre/beagle2/ams/testing/hpc_python_2015/examples/4_mpi4py/hello.py &
cd ..

Comment: what do you mean by 'it doesn't run'? does it throw any error? i only see `echo` statements inside the loop.

Comment: echo should show the result of this execution: aprun -n 32 python /lustre/beagle2/ams/testing/hpc_python_2015/examples/4_mpi4p‌​y/hello.py. Where I am running 32 instances on this python hello.py script with aprun command.

Comment: there is no error, just in say job_2 there is only qscript and no putput of my command running

Comment: because you are not running commands, you are only printing what's inside the quotes in a file called qscript. what are your intentions regarding these lines? do you want to execute whats inside the quotes?

Comment: yes I want to execute what is inside those lines, can you please show me how to do it

Comment: ok, so you need to get rid of those `echo`, check my updated answer

Comment: but when do you execute: qsub qscript?In your version that never gets created

Comment: should  `qsub qscript` be executed in each of the `job_$i` folders? i fail to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: the problem was directory levels, so I had to put things like this: echo "cd job_$i" >> ../../qscript. Also I had to create job_0, cd there and then do inside my for loop for the child jobs.. Now it works